# How to stop service with 'Run Anything' in WebStorm?

Tags: node.js, debugging, ide, webstorm

In the recent release WebStorm [(2019.3) introduce 'Run Anything action'](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/whatsnew/#v2019-3-ide), 
now i can easily **start** npm services etc, but:

How can i **stop these services** by using the same 'Run Anything'?.

Thank you very much!

*edit: 
I found out how to start debug session using the 'Run Anything', [and i split it to separate Q&A.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59052744/how-to-start-debug-session-with-run-anything-in-webstorm/59052745#59052745)

Comment: please attach a screenshot of the error message. What do you mean by running it manually?

Comment: @lena manually mean - by my mouse in the GUI. the error massage less relevant. my question is about doing it with my keyboard - in .Run Anything

Answer (score 1):

1. Using the **Stop** button in IDE *Navigation bar*/appropriate *Ru*n tool window that opens once you start the task
2. It's started with **Debug** button and stopped with **Stop** (see above).
   see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.3/running-and-debugging-node-js.html#node_debugging_running_application

Comment: Thank you for your time for trying to answering, but you answered about start/stop debugging in general, and not about 'Run Anything' action, as my question refer to. Thank to you i edited my question trying to clarify my original meaning

Comment: it was about 'Run Anything' action; it starts a run configuration and opens a tool window with appropriate controls

Comment: my config is all in place, how can i stop the service i just started with the 'Run Anything action' NOT by clicking the IDE GUI around?

Comment: try the shortcut assigned to **Run | Stop** action