# How to start debug session with 'Run Anything' in WebStorm?

Tags: node.js, debugging, ide, webstorm

In the recent release WebStorm [(2019.3) introduce 'Run Anything action'](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/whatsnew/#v2019-3-ide), 
that great to easily start services etc'.

Until now i use to run it by clicking on the 'start debug' GUI button, and that works great, but how can i start debugging session like 'Attach to Node.js' by using the 'Run Anything' action?

When i try to run with 'Run Anything' - i get 'cannot find runner for Node' failing error massage, that not appear when i trying to run it by the GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you open the 'Run Anything' modal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>), hold the <kbd>shift</kbd> while you choosing the debugging session you want.